# Append function outcome to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I try to assign values depening on a loop to a dataframe in python.

I have the following start dataframe:

```
thres = 0.1
d = { 'T': [0.], 'TN': [0], 'FN': [0], 'FP':[0], 'TP':[0]}
dataframef = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

with my start varialbe `thres`.

Now I am entering my loop:

```
while thres <= 0.4:
    a = { 'T': [0], 'TN': [0], 'FN': [0], 'FP':[0], 'TP':[0]}
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
    y_pred = predictionthreshold(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42), thres)
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test.ravel(), y_pred).ravel()
    dataframe.loc[0]['T'] = thres
    dataframe.loc[0]['TN'] = tn
    dataframe.loc[0]['FP'] = fp
    dataframe.loc[0]['FN'] = fn
    dataframe.loc[0]['TP'] = tp    
    dataframef = dataframef.append(dataframe, ignore_index=True)
    thres=thres+0.1
```

My outcome is:

```
    T   TN  FN  FP  TP
0   0.0     0   0   0   0
1   0.0     0   0   0   0
2   0.0     0   0   0   0
3   0.0     0   0   0   0
4   0.0     0   0   0   0
```

I would expected something, which fills the dataframe step by step:

```
    T   TN  FN  FP  TP
0   0.1     1   0   0   0
1   0.2     0   3   0   0
2   0.3     0   0   2   0
3   0.4     0   0   0   0
4   0.5     0   4   0   4
```

Where is the error in it? and is there elegant way to avoid an loop?

Comment: What is `predictionthreshold`? There is no definition for it.

Comment: predictionthreshold is my inviduel function, which returns 4 variables, I store them in TN, FN, FP, TP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the assignments like this:

```
dataframe.loc[0,'T'] = thres
dataframe.loc[0,'TN'] = tn
dataframe.loc[0,'FP'] = fp
dataframe.loc[0,'FN'] = fn
dataframe.loc[0,'TP'] = tp
```

When using `dataframe.loc[0]['TP'] = tp` you assign `tp` to a copy, not to the original dataframe. For details see [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

Comment: this is working, thx for the hint, any idea why it does not work with a copy?

Comment: any idea to avoid the while loop?

Comment: Because you get a modified copy that it nowhere used further down in your programm. I added a link to the pandas documention for further details.

Comment: The loop is attributed to your program logic, but if you want to simplify it, you can directly append the results with `dataframef = dataframef.append({ 'T': thres , 'TN': tn, 'FN': fn, 'FP':fp, 'TP':tp}, ignore_index=True)` without creating the temporary `dataframe`.